# How to add label when merge request is created on gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, merge-request

I would like to add label "foo" once merge request is created.

How can I do it?

If not possible via gitlab gui (using some robot) it is possible via gitlab api?

Comment: Do you want to label the MR or the issue?

Comment: I would like to label MR.

Answer (score 2):

You’d have to register a new Webhook, then have something listen and check for the Merge Request Event (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#merge-request-events).

Then you’ll have to parse it, checking the `object_attributes.state` field to see if the MR was created, updated, merged, closed, or pushed to, and grab the ID in `object_attributes.id`., Then you can use the Merge Request API to add a label to the MR. You’ll have to use the Update MR operation and change the labels (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#update-mr)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so using [Gitlab quick actions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/quick_actions.html) in the merge requests' default description.

In `Gitlab` on the project level go to: 
`Settings -> Merge requests -> Default description template for merge requests`

and set the following description: 
`/label ~123 ~"my-label"` 
where `123` - is the id of one **existed** label and `my-label` is the name of another **existed** label. If labels do not exist - it will not work.